# DDMS reporting incorrect memory usage?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, ddms

I'm currently investigating one of our Android applications for memory leaks and I found something that completely baffles me.

The DDMS heap monitor reports that the application is using 13mb/20mb heap memory, but a report pulled directly from the device is reporting that the application is using nearly 700mb!

Is this an issue with the device? Is DDMS wrong? How do I find out what is going into that 700mb?

[image]
[image]

Comment: "a report pulled directly from the device is reporting that the application is using nearly 700mb!" -- um, that's well past the heap limit. So, unless you're using NDK code, that shouldn't be possible. What exactly is this "report"?

Comment: it is information that is logged periodically, displaying the memory usage of applications currently running.

Comment: "it is information that is logged periodically, displaying the memory usage of applications currently running" -- then perhaps there is a bug in how you are doing this.

Comment: It is part of the system software. I'm busy adding images now. You will notice all the other applications' memory usage appear "normal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is part of the system software

The first screenshot is the output of `adb shell dumpsys meminfo`. The second screenshot looks like it is from `procrank`, which isn't part of standard Android; leastways, I can't find it quickly on Android 6.0.

(in the future, when somebody asks you 'what exactly is this "report"', feel free to cite actual commands)

> Is this an issue with the device?

Probably not, though that's tough to say, since we do not know what the device is, what the app is, or much of anything outside of two digital camera photos.

> Is DDMS wrong?

Probably not. Java code, whether running in Dalvik or ART, has a heap limit, and that's going to be well under 700MB.

> How do I find out what is going into that 700mb?

~600MB of that will be coming from native code (NDK libraries), most likely.

So, start by finding out what in your app is using native code. That could be your code, or it could come from third-party libraries (e.g., Fresco). Your choices then are:

- Call (or implement) logic in those libraries to cap how much heap space they use, or
- Get rid of them, or
- See if there's a way of hooking up Valgrind or something else to NDK code to determine where and how those libraries are using so much system RAM

Comment: " which isn't part of standard Android; leastways" -- Yes, it is a device developed by a private company. I believe they are using a customized version of Android
"feel free to cite actual commands, and feel free to copy and paste text "--  I did not execute any commands to the device, neither did I have direct access to copy the text. Unlike standard Android devices, there isn't a way to connect directly to this device. I had to use a third party application to retrieve the information, in turn the best I could do was to take photos.

Comment: One other symptom is that the application is terminated. But with no trace. Nothing is shown in the log, and the exception handlers isn't invoked as well. (Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler ). Is this the expected behavior in this situation?

Comment: @EZFrag: Regarding your first comment, my apologies. You're in a rather unusual situation. "One other symptom is that the application is terminated" -- well, processes get terminated all the time in Android, when they are in the background. If you mean that your app is vanishing while in the foreground, I would have expected something to be logged to LogCat, though potentially not a stack trace. In theory, even the current foreground process could be terminated to free up system RAM, and if that were ever to occur, your memory profile would be one situation I could see causing it.

Comment: @EZFrag: However, IIRC, LogCat contains entries (probably at info or debug level) that mention when processes are terminated to free up system RAM. I don't know if you can get to LogCat on this device (if you can't run commands, I don't know how you could get to LogCat...), but if you can, copy it somewhere and `grep` for your application ID.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have been able to reproduce the scenario on an alternative device with the information you have provided. One of the functions of the application is to use a WebView to display web widgets. In order to save bandwidth, we intercepted the requests made to images, downloading them and caching them locally, and them load them as necessary without downloading them again..

Comment: @EZFrag: Unless the caching is done in NDK-allocated system RAM, this would not explain the process working set size (i.e., the 700MB). So, for example, if you are using Facebook's Fresco library, it might have this effect, because they use NDK-allocated system RAM for caching images.

Comment: Though I'm fairly sure that if the code contained the said leak, it was supposed to appear in the DDMS. But, seeing as to how the WebView object actually interfaces with what ever "webview" object the local Android firmware provides, it must be that anything pertaining the WebView is handled by the NDK? Which is , as you suggested, why we can't detect it using the DDMS. Does this reasoning make sense to you?

Comment: @EZFrag: "it must be that anything pertaining the WebView is handled by the NDK?" -- `WebView` itself is implemented in native code, though not necessarily by the NDK. However, the only way that would explain matters is if you are doing the caching from JavaScript in memory (versus JavaScript to disk, Java in memory, etc.).